# Difference in coordinates between `imshow` and `quiver`

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to figure out the difference in conventions between `imshow` and `quiver`. When I run the following code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

img = np.random.randn(20, 40)
xs, ys = [15], [30]
us, vs = [4], [9]
plt.imshow(img, origin='lower')
plt.quiver(xs, ys, us, vs, scale_units='xy', angles='xy', scale=1)
plt.show()
```

I expect to have an arrow drawn, which fits within the range of `img` (since `15 + 4 < 20` and `30 + 9 < 40`). However, I get an image like this:[image: arrow outside the plot region]

and to get the expected result I need to transpose the image `img` or switch `xs` with `ys` and `us` with `vs`. With `plt.imshow(img.T)` I get the expected result[image: arrow within the plot region]. There are probably some conventions which I am missing and I would like to figure out which. This is annoying when overlaying vector fields over rgb images, as it's easy to lose track of coordinate systems when transposing.

Comment: `imshow` interpretes the first dimension of the array as vertical. This is consistent with how the array "looks like", i.e. rows of the array are rows in the image.

Comment: What would be the easiest and most error-proof way to reinterpret it, such that it works for single-channel and rgb arrays alike? `img.T` doesn't cut it for rgb and `.transpose(1, 0, 2)` is somewhat prone to errors when I'm tired. The point is I am using these plots when debugging and having a bug in ones' debugging code is a nightmare.

Comment: I would not actually reinterprete at all, because that definition is used throughout other imaging tools as well.